# Pointer doesnt work

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

My code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct element
{
    int liczba;
    element *nastepny;
    element();
};

element::element()
{
    nastepny=0;
}

int main()
{
    element pierwszy;
    pierwszy.liczba=1;
    element drugi;
    (*nastepny).pierwszy=2;
    drugi.liczba=2;
    return 0;
}
```

It says that *nastepny was not declared, but I do not know how is it possible. I created structure with *nastepny. If I write element *nastepny, it says that element has no member named pierwszy. SOmething is going wrong because pierwszy is declared at the beginning of main function.

Comment: I assure you, pointers work.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you intend with "(*nastepny).pierwszy=2;"?

Comment: maybe on your computer :) but not on mine... everything is declared so how can it say that it is not?

Comment: @user3162968: Ever think that perhaps your understanding is what is wrong here?

Comment: I want that pointer *nastepny of structure member "pierwszy" (which is supposed not to be declared although I declared it) point to element drugi, which value is 2.

Comment: @user3162968: You got the other two assignments right.  Why do you think that accessing that pointer is any different?

Comment: Ed S, yes, it is also possible that my understanding is wrong... but I do not know the exact way it is wrong :)

Comment: Earlier I just wrote pierwszy.*nastepny=2, but I got error about types etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(*nastepny).pierwszy=2;
```

That makes no sense as `nastepny` is not declared statically or within its current or any parent scope.  It is a member of your structure and only exists as a part of and instance of one.

Also, you cannot simply assign two to the address of some unallocated pointer.  You have a pointer, but it does not yet point anywhere valid.  So, either:

```
drugi.nastepny = malloc(sizeof *drugi.nastepny);
*drugi.nastepny = whatever;
```

To allocate space dynamically, or...

```
drugi.nastepny = &some_variable;
```

But watch for lifetime issues on that last one.

Comment: struct element
{
 int liczba;
 element *nastepny;
// element();
};

/*element::element()
{
 nastepny=0;
}*/

int main()
{
 element pierwszy;
 pierwszy.liczba=1;
 element drugi;
 drugi.liczba=2;
 pierwszy.nastepny = &drugi;
 pierwszy.nastepny->liczba = 2;
 cout<<pierwszy.nastepny;
 return 0;
}

Comment: @user3162968: yeah ok

Comment: My code does not return value of pierwszy, just address starting on 0x. How can I fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: @user3162968: It's difficult to read that comment, but you're printing the value of the pointer.  A pointer's value is an address.  If you want to get at the thing it refers to then you must dereference it, i.e., `cout << pierwszy.nastepny->liczba `

Comment: Now it works as I wanted, thanks. Nevertheless I feel like I do not understand this at all and I need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens in

```
(*nastepny).pierwszy=2;
  ^^^^^^^^
```

`nastepny` is not declared in this scope. The member of the struct doesn't make it accessible outside the struct (instances).

I guess you are meaning something like this:

```
drugi.nastepny = &pierwszy;
drugi.nastepny->liczba = 2;
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 Which part is UB?

Answer (score 1):

I auggest this:

```
pierwszy.nastepny = &drugi;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you expect to get an object when you deference your pointer when you never assigned it a memory address?

If you want to get a pointer to the object itself then you can use the `this` pointer. However in this scenario such an application of it would make no sense.

The only assignment you provided to the element pointer was 0 (NULL), so it's not pointing to any element object.